# Auto resize QByteArray mix audio

Tags: c++, qt

I have multiple QByteArray of different length for example

i need to have new array size of max size of QByteArray in a QUEUE.
for example 
if Queue.value(1).size = 1
and Queue.value(2).size = 4, 
i need mixBuff size of 4.

```
QMultiHash<int *, QByteArray> Queue;
int maxBytesCount = 0;
foreach (QByteArray buf, Queue.values()) {
if (buf.size() > maxBytesCount)
maxBytesCount = buf.size(); 
}
```

and then i need something like

```
int CountInt16 = maxBytesCount / 2;
QByteArray mixBuff;
mixBuff.fill(0,maxBytesCount);

foreach (QByteArray buf, QUEUE.values()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < CountInt16; i++) {
        qint16* samples = (qint16*)buf.data(); 
        mixBuff[i] = (mixBuff[i] >> 1) + (samples[i] >> 1); 
    }
} 
// ...  
device()->write(mixBuff);
```

but i wanna do it without  find max QByteArray length.
if do not wanna check size of all elements QByteAray in QMultiHash

```
   QByteArray mixBuff;
   qint16 * myvalue16 = (qint16 *)mixBuff.data();
   for(int i = 0, a = 0; i < size; i++, a+=2) {
   qint32 sample32 = (qint16)myvalue16[i] + mixBuff[a];  
   }
```

but problem is that mixBuff[a] when auto resize will fill new  space with random value not zero. How can i fix thos фnd did not affect the original sum.